# What is the name for an IC that accepts an analog voltage and outputs a proportional PWM signal?

Tags: integrated-circuit, analog, pwm, converter

I want to isolate an analog signal. One way of doing this is to convert the analog signal to PWM, isolate the pulses with an optoisolator, and filter the PWM on the other side. Obviously I could do this with a microcontroller, but I feel like "convert analog to PWM" is a generic enough function that there should be an IC to do exactly that. Like most things, it's difficult to google something if you don't already know the name. What am I looking for?

Comment: a phase width modulator?

Comment: this Maxim application note may be useful: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to this post: [Easiest way to go from analog input to PWM output?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37079/easiest-way-to-go-from-analog-input-to-pwm-output)

The LTC6992 is the specific IC that`s suggested, and seems to fit your application