# DC/DC: Analog --> PWM 12V

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, pwm, converter

I'm looking for an IC that can convert an analog signal to a PWM signal, i.e.:

- Ui = 0V --> DC = 0%
- Ui = 6V --> DC = 50%
- Ui = 12V--> DC = 100%

Anyone who knows an IC for this?

Thank you

Comment: This is simple to do with a few op amps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, can you think of any other ways, I'd like to use only one IC and no to many extra components

Comment: Is an MCU ok? Even opamp would be very few external components.

Comment: @TimJager Well, with that "a few op amps" you can do it with a single quad op amp IC, or like winny suggested a small MCU, maybe even a tiny little SOT-23-6 package PIC or something if they make one like that.

Comment: Search the internet on "voltage to pwm ic" or "voltage to pwm controller". Maybe you need to be creative to convert the range from 0V...12V to e.g. 0V ... 1V or to e.g. 0.5V...3.5V.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone who knows an IC for this?

Yes, I do: -

[image]

Comment: I was waiting for this! ;^)

Answer (score 0):

[Easiest way to go from analog input to PWM output?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37079/easiest-way-to-go-from-analog-input-to-pwm-output)

https://www.st.com/en/power-management/pwm-controllers.html#2

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4502

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl5002.pdf

Above linkS will help you.